# Botao não funciona em SetInterval

Tags: javascript

Opa,

Tenho um set interval:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#loading_questions").load("include/question.php?id_question=1");
    }, 8000);
});
```

Dentro do arquivo question.php tenho um botão com uma determinada classe, que ao ser acionada chama uma função javascript.
O que quero saber é se há existe algum tipo de bloqueio num setinterval ao chamar uma funcao javascript por onclick ou por classe.

Vlw

Answer (score 0):

você precisa recarregar o evento após fazer o load. Você pode automatizar isto utilizando o `.on()`.

então substitua no seu script algo semelhante à isto:

```
$("<selector do botão>").click(function (event) { ... })
//ou
$("<selector do botão>").on("click", function (event) { ... })
```

pelo o seguinte:

```
$("#loading_questions").on("click", "<selector do botão>", function (event) { ... })
```